# Create plus and minus buttons like date picker

Tags: android

Is there a way to create a plus and minus button like the ones in the date picker dialog?
I mean without create them from scratch.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes Take button and display plus/minus background into it.

Comment: Yes but I have to create a new drawable. I thought there was the plus button drawable in the android.R package, or something like that.

Comment: @DanieleVitali you are right there are set of drawables that you can use from android.R.drawable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to do what Paresh mayani suggested.

You can set Background for your Button with android resource available. Datapicker uses a arrow up and arrow down resources available (android.R.drawable) . Instead of creating custom images and setting the same as a background to button, you can use the available ones. For list of all android drawables that you can use is available in the link below

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

To set the background programatically

```
 Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 b.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
```

Set background in xml

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
     />
```

Answer (score -1):

Below are some links to resources that give you quick visuals of the android resources. I didn't see anything that exactly matches your needs, but maybe you can get a bit creative :)  Don't forget to make sure to check version specifics if you are using them.

http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

http://androiddrawables.com/buttons.html

Comment: links are broken